# Mysqli bind_param for column name in update query

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

Is it possible to use bind_param in update query where column's name can dynamically changes?

for example

```
sql='update table_1 set ? = ? where id=?'
```

In the query above, I want to set the column name also by `bind_param`, but it causes error.

Comment: You can't bind columnames in mysql.

Comment: for db object as table or column name you can't use binding param but you could use dinamic sql  .. (sql string dinamically cretated)

Comment: Understood.Thx to all